# Usando regex en Python como separar un número decimal de un string sin que lean caracteres especiales y caracteres cómo ñ

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

Quisiera saber cómo separar de una cadena de texto un número decimal, exceptuando caracteres cómo ñ, tildes entre otros:
Ejemplo:

```
str1 = 'niño13.8'
resultado = 13.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entiendo a qué te refieres con "separando", para mi significa que quieres añadir una variable para la parte decimal y otra para la parte no decimal.

Por tu ejemplo, parece que sólo quieres obtener la parte decimal. Si es ese el caso, utiliza algo por el estilo.

```
>>> import re
>>> patron = r'[+-]?\d*\.?\d+'
>>> str1 = 'niño13.8'
>>> str2 = 'niña12'
>>> str3 = 'niño11aaff'
>>> str4 = 'niña10.12ff'
>>> str5 = 'niño.9ff'
>>> re.findall(patron, str1)
['13.8']
>>> re.findall(patron, str2)
['12']
>>> re.findall(patron, str3)
['11']
>>> re.findall(patron, str4)
['10.12']
>>> re.findall(patron, str5)
['.9']
```

Y ya puedes interactuar con las listas, en cambio, si quieres separarlos (como yo entendí) tanto en la palabra como en el decimal, puedes hacer otra expresión regular de la forma `^[a-zA-Zñ]`.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

patron_word = ur'^[a-zA-Zñ]+'
patron_float = r'[+-]?\d*\.?\d+'

pruebas = [
    'niño13.8',
    'niña12',
    'niño11aaff',
    'niña10.12ff',
    'niño.9ff',
    'niña-19.03'
]

for v in pruebas:
    print '%s -> %s' % (re.findall(patron_word,
                                    v.decode('utf-8'), re.UNICODE)[0],
                        re.findall(patron_float, v,)[0])
```

En este caso, al ejecutarlo, resulta algo de este estilo.

```
niño -> 13.8
niña -> 12
niño -> 11
niña -> 10.12
niño -> .9
niña -> -19.03
```

Podrías asignar cada uno a una variable diferente simplemente la forma.

```
var1 = re.findall(patron1...)[0 o 1 o 2 o el que quieras de la lista]
var2 = re.findall(patron2...)[0 o 1 o 2 o el que quieras de la lista]
```